# Get the last 12 months in PHP from Month Year Given

Tags: php, date

Problem: I need to find year-month strings between two given dates in the format "Y-m".

I have this, but it does not work:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $months[] = date("Y-m%", strtotime(date('Y-m-01') . " -$i months"));
}
```

Because this starts today, and only for 12 month.

Example given date:

```
11-2015 to 05-2018
```

Comment: because you have `$i <= 12`.  Once $i hits 13, the loop will be finished..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DatePeriod](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) to get a range of dates between 2 `DateTimes`, then use [DateTime::format()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to get what ever date string you want from those dates (in your case 'Y-m'):

```
<?php
$dates = new DatePeriod(new DateTime('2015-01'), new DateInterval('P1M'), new DateTime('2018-05'));
$date_strings = array_map(function($d) { return $d->format('Y-m'); }, iterator_to_array($dates));
print_r($date_strings);
```

Gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-01
    [1] => 2015-02
    [2] => 2015-03
    [3] => 2015-04
    [4] => 2015-05
    [5] => 2015-06
    ...
    [39] => 2018-04
)
```

Comment: ok @spinkus but the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51432537/9632001 have the same result but which is the most efficient

Comment: They are both `O(n)` and pretty trivial, but I would hazard a guess the above is more efficient - less function calls, less lines. It is also easier to read IMO, and more extensible: once you have your DatePeriod iterable you can do whatever you want with it from there.

Answer (score 1):

correct way:

```
                $date1=$s_list_102."-".$s_list_101."-01"; //month and year merge on date 1
                $date2=$s_list_104."-".$s_list_103."-01"; //month and year merge on date 1
                $d1 = strtotime($date1);
                $d2 = strtotime($date2);
                $min_date = min($d1, $d2);
                $max_date = max($d1, $d2);
                $c = 0;
                while (($min_date = strtotime("+1 MONTH", $min_date)) <= $max_date) {
                    $c++;
                }
                for ($i = 0; $i <= $c; $i++) {
                    $months[] = date("M-y", strtotime(date($date2) . " -$i months"));
                }
```